# How to rename list on double click but keep the icons next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with  along with icons , Im using this javascript function to allow user to rename the element and change it, but how do i make it so that the icon will still remain but the name will change? Currently i remove() the current name and replace it with the new one and obviously it would rem,ove the icon as well.. how do i keep the icon (could be multiple different ones) even tho the names change.

List -

```
     <ul id="sourceList" class="sub-menu" style="color:black; text-align: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll;max-height: 350px; list-style:none;" aria-expanded="true">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName </span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Javascript -

```
 var oriVal;
$("#sourceList").on('dblclick', 'a', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
});
$("#sourceList").on('focusout', 'a > input', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().text($this.val() || oriVal);
    $this.remove();
});
```

See Fiddle example - [Rename List](https://jsfiddle.net/sqmnagwe/)

Comment: Instead of `$(this).text("");` try `$(this).find("span").text("");`

Comment: Did this already, but how to i remove the a but not the i when changing the value? cause even tho im only editing the span the icon is still deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the image to a global variable, then restore it using this variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var oriVal;
  var oriIcon;
  $("#sourceList").on('dblclick', 'a', function() {
    oriIcon = $(this).find('i');
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");
    $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
  });
  $("#sourceList").on('focusout', 'a > input', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().text($this.val() || oriVal).prepend(oriIcon);
    $this.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sourceList" class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName </span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this you want to implement?

```js
$("#sourceList").on('dblclick', 'a', function () {
    oriVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).find('span').text("");
    $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
});
$("#sourceList").on('focusout', 'a > input', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().find('span').text($this.val() || oriVal);
    $this.remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <ul id="sourceList" class="sub-menu" style="color:black; text-align: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll;max-height: 350px; list-style:none;" aria-expanded="true">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName </span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the original `DOM`.
Also, I would advise not to use global variables -

```js
$("#sourceList").on('dblclick', 'a', function() {
  $("<input type='text'>").appendTo(this).focus();
  $(this).find('span').text('');
});
$("#sourceList").on('focusout', 'a > input', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings('span').text(this.value);
  $this.remove();
});
```

```html
<ul id="sourceList" class="sub-menu" style="color:black; text-align: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll;max-height: 350px; list-style:none;" aria-expanded="true">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>SourceName </span></a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```